# Probability that a dart hits a target

Tags: probability

Find the probability that a dart hits a marked region provided that every spot is equally likely to be hit and that it could possibly not hit the target at all. It appears to me that if the probability of hitting inside the region is $p$, then it is probably equal to something like $\frac{P(\text{marked region})}{P(\text{unmarked region})}$. It could either go outside the region or be inside. I need some good explanation for this, since the unmarked area is extremely large compared to the marked area (which is a definite area) yet the probability is often **finite**, as I see as examples everywhere.

Comment: It should be $\frac{P_{marked\,region}}{P_{total\,region}}$.

Comment: By finite, do you mean$ >0.1$ ?

Comment: If a region is marked on the wall, any part of the earth that does not lie inside the marked boundary is the total region. That's what I am talking about. It's indefinitely a big region. @sai-kartik Not in particular but yes, I mean something $\neq 0$. That can not necessarily be counted yet it is not zero, right? But something that tends to zero maybe?

Comment: This kind of seems similar to the problems concerning the density of rational numbers in a closed interval.

Comment: I think the examples you have seen, have considered some part of the dartboard to be non-scorabale. I have an answer that follows this assumption. Would you be interested in reading it?

Comment: Do we know the probability that the target is not hit at all? I mean, it makes a big difference ...

Comment: We do not know the probability. This is a very general question I asked. If the probability that the target hit is $p$, how does it make sense that $P_{marked}/P_{earth} = p$? A best I can see is that it's not countable.


@sai-kartik sure

Answer (score 0):

Let's use some actual dart data to get a clear picture. (Data was pulled from [this](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Ebolo/darts/dartboard.html#:%7E:text=Steel-Tip%20Board%20Target%20Areas,-The%20following%20dimensions&text=Inner%20Bull%20--%201%2F2,6-11%2F16%22%20radius) site. )

We have the total board diameter to be $18$ inches and the playable diameter- $13 \frac14$ inches. Since you have mentioned that the dart may not hit the target (playable dart area) at all, I shall go with the total area to be $\pi\frac{(18)^2}{4} \text{  in}^2$

And let's say we desire the dart to hit the inner bullseye who's area is $0.2 \text { in}^2$

So now the probability of the dart hitting our desired area, is simply the ratio of the desired area and the total area which would be:

$$P(\text{dart hitting bullseye})=\frac{0.2 \times 4}{18 \pi^2}\approx 4.5\times 10^{-3}$$

Comment: My point was, the non-playable area is not defined like it is in your example. It could be the entire world, or basically, calculate how far your dart goes and your throw could land anywhere.

Comment: Hmm, that changes everything. Could you link an example that you have seen?